# Setting python.path for VS Code Python Debugger for Multi-root workspace with multiple virtual environments

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-3.6

I have a multi-root workspace with three directories in VS Code. I source a different virtual environment when I need to run scripts from each project directory (two of which are Flask Apps). I would like to set up the debugger but what do I put as my python path in launch.json and settings.json, since the path and env changes for each directory? Please provide an example of the settings needed for each file when working with a multi-root workspace in debug mode. My current configuration is Python: Current File when in the Debugger.

```
"pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
```

Comment: You'll need to create a `launch.json` for each workspace (directory). Using a single `launch.json` will always result in `${workspaceFolder}` pointing to the workspace it belongs to.

Comment: Right now launch.json and settings.json are under the .vscode directory(which auto generated). Are you saying I should make three copies of the .vscode directory to put into each of my project directories or just place the .json files straight into my three other dirs?

Comment: Each directory as they are treated as separate workspaces by VS Code.

Comment: I moved the launch.json into one of the other directories but when I go to debug it asks me to configure the debugger. Upon selecting Python it again auto-generates .vscode with launch json at the level of my other workspaces. When I run the debugger I get Module Not found Errors which lead me to believe the problem is that the launch.json is not seeing the env for the current py I am debugging. I don't believe the debugger is accessing the copy of the launch.json within its own directory. Can I add multiple environment paths to the one launch.json that autogenerates in the .vscode dir?

Comment: Specifically, when I run my file that imports the requests library in debug mode it says Module Not Found although it has been installed via a pip install and requirements.txt

Comment: In the bottom left corner of VScode, I selected virtualenv as interpeter and it's now seeing the imported modules. I did not move my launch.json file and did not change any of its configurations.